# How to reduce the value from multiple rows by calculation

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have table called : stock  , From that qty will be reduced by priority column in the respective warehouse.

```
-------------------------------------------
Id         SKU    priority  Warehouse  Qty
--------------------------------------------
1          sku1      p1        W1        1
2          sku1      p2        w2        2
3          sku1      p3        w3        3
```

From the above table, 4 qty item will be reduced based on priority.

Expected output :

```
------------------------------------------
Id         SKU    priority  Warehouse  Qty
--------------------------------------------
1          sku1      p1        W1        0
2          sku1      p2        w2        0
3          sku1      p3        w3        2
```

Can anyone suggest how to achieve it.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
 an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
 then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
 [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/),
 how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: It is far from clear what you are asking us to do for you. You will always get a better response from this community if you show that you have attempted to solve a requirement yourself before asking here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be the starting point:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc_LOOP(IN quantity INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE x INT;
    DECLARE id_temp int;
    DECLARE quantity_temp int;
    SET x = 0;

    loop_label:
    LOOP
        SELECT Qty, Id INTO quantity_temp,id_temp 
        FROM stock 
        WHERE SKU = 'sku1' AND Qty != 0 ORDER BY priority LIMIT 1;
            IF x + quantity_temp >= quantity THEN
                UPDATE stock SET Qty= (x + quantity_temp - quantity) WHERE Id = id_temp;
                LEAVE loop_label;
            ELSE
                UPDATE stock SET Qty=0 WHERE Id = id_temp;
                SET x = (x + quantity_temp);
            END IF;
    END LOOP;
END$$
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cfrhWey8oVKGK83XELJCsb/1).

The hearth of the programm is `IF (x + quantity_temp >= quantity)` update with the remaining quantity; otherwise update with quatity 0 and repeat loop.

You can use `FOUND_ROWS()` in cases the quantity is higher than stock. Find documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

This only works with 'sku1' but you can pass more parameters to the SP

Comment: Hi Alberto, Thanks its working fine. Thank you so much